# Can ping subnet ip, but can not socket.connect

Tags: python, c, sockets, networking, subnet

I have a server, which is hosted on a subnet. I gave it the ip 10.130.28.130.
I have a client on a different subnet. Through that client I can ping the server, however I cannot connect to it.

SERVER [C]:

```c
    int ipStatus = system("ifconfig eth0 10.130.28.130");
    int netmaskStatus = system("ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0");


    #define PORT = 8080
    void server()
    {
        int serverSocket, newSocket;
        struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
        struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
        socklen_t addr_size;
        int opt = TRUE;

        //Create socket
        serverSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (setsockopt(serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, 
            sizeof(opt))<0)
            error("SETSOCKOPT ERROR");

        //Configure setting of the server address struct
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

        //Set all bits of the padding field to 0 
        memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);

        //Bind the address struct to the socket 
        bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

        //Listen on the socket, with max 40 connection requests queued

        if(listen(serverSocket,40)==0)
          printf("\nListening\n");
        else
          printf("\nError\n");
        pthread_t tid[60];
        int i = 0;
        while(1)
        {
          //Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection
          addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
          newSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
          //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
          //for each client request creates a thread and assign the client request to it to process
          //so the main thread can entertain next request
          if( pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, socketThread, (void *)(uintptr_t) newSocket) != 0 )
              printf("\nFailed to create thread\n");
          else
          {
              printf("\nSOCKET %i CREATED\n", newSocket);
          }

          if( i >= 50)
          {
              i = 0;
              while(i < 50)
              {
                  pthread_join(tid[i++],NULL);
              }
              i = 0;
          }
        }
    }
```

The client [PYTHON]:

```py
    def try_connect(address):
        global connected
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(address)
        connected = True
        return [client, connected]

    ip = socket.gethostbyname("10.130.28.130")
    port = int(8080)
    address = (ip,port)
```

Before, it worked, when they were both on the same network and I set the IP to a local address (eg. 192.168.0.13).

I can ping both the client and the server from a terminal on both subnets. What am I missing?

**EDIT clarifying network setup**

[image: Network setup]

Comment: ping (ICMP) is it's own protocol, which doesn't use ports at all.  So you can still ping a host that isn't listening on a particular port (TCP/UDP).

Comment: Agreed, but it still means that somehow I should be able to connect to it, as it states the server is actually there. Right? What am I doing wrong, causing me to not being able to connect?

Comment: Can you connect using `nc 10.130.28.130 8080`? You can use this tool to check whether connecting to the server is even possible.

Comment: Neh, that doesn't work. What makes the difference when you are able to connect through a subnet? The only thing the server does, is stream data over send data over a single port.

Comment: what IP does the server and the client have and your computer ?

Comment: The client software runs on my pc [10.130.28.155], connected to a router 10.130.28.1.
The server software runs on a small linux unit with an IP I can choose [now 10.130.28.130], this unit is connected to a router 10.130.28.49.
Both these routers serve as AP for the same network.

Comment: Can I program the access into either my client or server, or do I need to allow this in my routers?